# Display Suite code field – how to use another image field conditionally

Tags: 7, theming, display-suite

In my content type I want to show the main image if the thumbnail field is empty. So I use the Display Suite code field and I enter the following code:

```
<?php 
dsm($entity);
if(empty($entity->field_thumbnail)){
    print_r('Thumbnail missing');
    // What code to put here to enable or render another image field 
}
?>
```

When the tumbnail is missing the above code works, but instead of text I want to display another image field, when the thumbnail is missing. I have tried everything I can think of, but the main image dose not show :-(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have nothing in renderable format yet.

Look at [function field_view_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.module/function/field_view_field/7)

> Returns a renderable array for the value of a single field in an
>   entity.

Then change your code like this:

```
<?php 
dsm($entity);
if(empty($entity->field_thumbnail)){
    $renderable = field_view_field('node',$entity,'field_main_image',array('settings' => array('image_style' => 'thumbnail')));
    print drupal_render($renderable );
}
?>
```

Note that this is not the only way to get html from field values. You can use theme functions and load that with values you find on $entity object and print that if you wish.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That made my day! I also added 'label' => 'hidden' and that was that. I will dig into field_view_field, another tool in the toolbox :-). Tried to give you an upvote apart from the right answer tick, but apparently my reputation is to modest for that so far. But many thanks again.